# Sending binary data from jQuery ajax to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, post, binary

I am trying to send binary data using jQuery `$.ajax()` to PHP, but my code doesn't quite work. I am hoping someone can help me out a little.

My situation: In the beginning, I didn't have to deal with binary data, I had an AJAX call and it worked very well.

```
$.ajax({
      dataType: 'json'
    , type: 'POST'
    , data: {foo:bar}
    , url: // url to send to ...
    ...
});
```

On PHP, I retrieved the data using `$foo = $_POST['foo'];`

Then later on, there was a need to increase the size of the data sending out. The JSON was so big that I had to seek out a compression lib/method. I picked [pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako) to compress the json string into Uint8 array. (If you think there is a better way to compress data before sending out JSON via AJAX, please advise, thank you. )

My code became:

```
var dataStr = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
var pako = window.pako;
var binData = pako.deflate(unescape(encodeURIComponent(dataStr))); // dataStr is now Uint8 array
$.ajax({
    ....
    , data:{binary:binData, foo:bar...} // and other data
    , contentType: false
    , processData: false
});
```

I don't know whether it is because of the binary format, but I can't retrieve data on the PHP side anymore. 
I have tried checking:

- `$_POST`
- `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`
- `file_get_contents('php://input')`

But I see nothing relevant *(Or may be I just don't know how to `var_dump`/`print_r` to debug the content of `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` and `file_get_contents('php://input')` ? I don't know)*.

Am I missing something here? Truly appreciated for the help.

Comment: This is the key, `processData: false` and you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a FormData object(with a blob) if you want to send binary data

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('binary', new Blob(binData));
fd.append('foo', 'bar');
binary:binData, foo:bar
$.ajax({
    ....
    , data:fd,
    , contentType: false
    , processData: false
});
```

then read it via `$_FILES['binData']`